# Separation of terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to translate this into the scientific calculator with $x=-4$:
$$f(x)=\frac{x^3-6x^2+11x-6}{x^3+x^2-10x+8}$$
To which I get:
$$-4^3 - 6(-4^2) + 11(-4) - 6 = -18$$
$$-4^3 - 4^2 - 10(-4) + 8 = -32$$
But people keep telling me the right results are $-210$ and 0.

Comment: Make sure you are taking powers correctly: when you have $-4$ cubed, you may need to enter $(-4)^3$ (that is, `(-4)^3` ) in the calculator. **Note:** this isn’t really a problem for odd powers, but it matters for even powers.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac{x^3-6x^2+11x-6}{x^3+x^2-10x+8}$$
$$f(-4)=\frac{(-4)^3-6(-4)^2+11(-4)-6}{(-4)^3+(-4)^2-10(-4)+8}$$
$$f(-4)=\dfrac{-64-96-44-6}{-64+16+40+8}=-\dfrac{210}{0}=\mbox{undefined}$$